# How to track whether the user is following my suggestion

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, geolocation

I am developing an geo location based app which suggest you restaurants nearby which are less crowded.So for a user it will suggest which restaurant to go to (The back end (java) does the suggestion ). But I(In The back end) want to know whether the user is following my suggestion or ignoring it. I have the user's latitude and longitude and the restaurant's latitude longitude.I can eventually calculate the distance between both but what is the efficient way to know whether the user is moving towards the restaurant or not (considering the restaurant are big)?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Track user's location and calculate direction from current/previous points?

Comment: But what is the speedest way to calculate that because the movement will be quiet fast if the user is in a vehicle

Comment: Definitely calculating based on 2 points (lat/lon) isfaster than any movement) Get the position each second and calculate direction (and speed). You can send the direction only to be faster.